# Identify user of comment and send notification Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a posts system. On my site, users can post articles and post comments on every article. I want to release: when any user (not author of the post) comment post, I need to send a notification to the author of the post, that post him was commented by UserName... I do it like this:

In CommentController I have a method for post comment on the post:

```
public function postComment(Post $post, AddPostRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->parent_id !== null) {
        $parent = Comment::where('id', $request->parent_id)->first();
        $this->authorize('canComment', $parent);
    }

    $data = [
        'user_id' => Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : null,
        'post_id' => $post->id
    ];

    $comment = $post->createComment(array_merge($request->except('g-recaptcha-response'), $data));

    $post->owner->sendReviewNotification($review);

    return $review;
}
```

In my comment system, I have nested comments. In model Post, I have the method `createReview.`

```
public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function createComment($data = [])
{
    $review = $this->comments()->create($data);

    return $review;
}
```

In model Comment I have:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(static::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotNull('user_id')->where('active', 1);
}
```

Now: when a comment is created, notifications are sent to the author of the post, but when an author can answer to comment of posting him, then notification send again to him, but I need send a notification to the author of the comment. How can I define this case? I don't need to send always notifications to an author of a post, I need notify and authors of comments, that comments them is answered by the author of the post.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to send and email notification to the author of the post via email class `sendReviewNotification` with `$review` as the parameter.
 if that is the case then this line

```php
$post->owner->sendReviewNotification($review);
```

because `$post->owner` returns an eloquent relationship(It is a query builder)

this is how I would do this.
I would use the relationship above to get the user's(Author) email address

```php
$post->owner->email
```

the line above will return the Authors email address

then use the mail Facade

```php
Mail::to($post->owner->email)->send(new sendReviewNotification($review));
```

I am assuming `sendReviewNotification` is your mail class
also remember to add this line at the beginning of your class just below the namespace.
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is to send a notification to every participant of the discussion, but only to the people that have commented since your last comment:

```
Post #4321 (Author Richard)
  -> Comment #1 by John
  -> Comment #2 by Elias
  -> Comment #3 by Richard    <-- the author
  -> Comment #4 by Michael
  -> Comment #5 by John
  -> Comment #6 by Merry
  -> Comment #7 by Richard    <-- the author
```

In this scenario, you probably want to send a notification in the following sitiations:

1. Richard is notified if someone commented on his post
2. The author of a comment is notified if Richard comments as well

---

The first situation seems straight forward. Whenever a new comment is created, you notify the author of the post which has been commented:

```
if ($comment->author_id !== $comment->post->author_id) {
    $comment->post->author->notify(new PostWasCommented($comment));
}
```

As you can see, I expect you to use the built-in [notification system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) of Laravel. It makes your life a lot easier to be honest.

---

The second situation is a bit more elaborate and allows again for two possible solutions:

- You send a notification to everyone who commented on the post before Richard commented.
  In the above example, when Richard creates comment #3, John and Elias would receive a notification. When Richard creates comment #7, then John, Elias, Michael and Merry receive a notification. *(`$comment` is the new comment to be created.)*

  ```
  $users = User::query()
      ->whereHas('comment', function ($query) use ($comment) {
          return $query->where('post_id', $comment->post_id);
      })
      ->where('user_id', '!=', $comment->post->author_id)
      ->get();

  foreach ($users as $user) {
      $user->notify(new PostWasCommented($comment));
  }
  ```
- You only send a notification to the people that commented since the last comment of the author.
  Projected on the above example, this means that John and Elias would be notified when Richard creates comment #3. And when Richard creates comment #7, then only Michael, John and Merry are notified - but not Elias. This is because only these three people have commented between #3 and #7.

  ```
  $users = User::query()
      ->whereHas('comment', function ($query) use ($comment) {
          return $query->where('post_id', $comment->post_id)
              ->where(
                 'created_at', 
                 '>', 
                 DB::raw(
                     "SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? AND author_id = ?", 
                     [$comment->post_id, $comment->author_id]
                 )
              );
      })
      ->where('user_id', '!=', $comment->post->author_id)
      ->get();

  foreach ($users as $user) {
      $user->notify(new PostWasCommented($comment));
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice. But in second situation where I need write your code? And I have a nested comments, every comment can have a children

Comment: I think you could write this in `sendReviewNotification($comment)`. Or you add an event called `CommentCreated` and put it into an event listener (probably the nicer solution as it decouples the logic). How you'd deal with nested comments depends a bit on how they are stored. Do nested comments also store the `post_id` or only the `parent_id` of the _previous (parent) comment_?

Comment: I have and `post_id` and `parent_id` on comments table.

Comment: Well, then why does the parent even matter? I think it is only interesting if you want to notify the author of the parent comment or post only, which would be a situation I've not included in my answer. It also isn't much different than what I described, as long as you don't use infinite nesting of comments.