# If there are more than two notifications, the data value should be change in laravel

Tags: laravel, notifications

The function I want to create is to include a notification function in posts, comments, likes, etc.

When writing a post,
Or when you comment on a post, etc.
(Currently, this is only applicable when you write a comment on a post)

I've created an AlarmNotification and confirmed that the notifications are stacking up in the database normally

[image]

I want to do some customization, for example,
User A writes a post
When user B comments on a post,
A notification should be sent to user A saying "Comment has been added".

When user C writes a comment on a post
User A says "2 comments have been added"
A notification should be sent

I'm having a hard time writing the above function

How can I make the above function ?

This article was written using Google Translate

Thanks

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524310/identify-user-of-comment-and-send-notification-laravel

Comment: @TheOneAboveAll 
When I went to the site you wrote down and read it, it was confirmed as an inquiry about a duplicate notification. In my case, the purpose is to change specific information in the notification that I have already sent. Can I get help?